# Thermodynamics Vapor Tables Problem

Tags: thermodynamics

> **3-29** A piston-cylinder device contains $\pu{0.85 kg}$ of refrigerant-134a at $\pu{-10^\circ C}$. The piston that is free to move has a mass of $\pu{12 kg}$ and a diameter of $\pu{25 cm}$. The local atmospheric pressure is $\pu{88 kPa}$. Now, heat is transferred to refrigerant-134a until the temperature is $\pu{15^\circ C}$. Determine (**a**) the final pressure, (**b**) the change in the volume of the cylinder, and (**c**) the change in the enthalpy of the refrigerant-134a.
>   [image]

This is my work so far...

[image]

These are the superheated R-134a vapor tables that are given:

[image]

Comment: For some reason this question is all over the internet and there are numerous solutions readily available from a brief Google search ([here](http://civil.colorado.edu/~silverst/aren2110/homework%202%20s10%20solutions.pdf) and [there](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~mcmurtry/Notes/2300_hw_5_sol.pdf)). Assuming there is no way you haven't seen them yet, probably you should explicitly state what is unclear to you and what is hard to understand. I'd suggest to handle units accurately, to start with, and don't mix apple and oranges.

Comment: Those are the same answers I got, so I suppose the solutions manual I'm using is either wrong or using EES yields more precise answers. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, I honestly looked only very briefly, but it may just be the matter of rounding off numbers. The only thing that draws attention is inconsistency in typography (e.g. pa, Pa, *Pa*), but hopefully you'll sort it out before submitting the papers.

Comment: Did you see my answer (below)?  Any questions?  Another (equivalent) way to do it accurately is to interpolate v with respect to 1/p rather than p.

Comment: Sorry, I just read your replies. You're right, I tried the second method (interpolating with respect to the inverse of p) and it worked as well. The only thing I'm having a problem understanding now is when to apply it. Is it done when the gas is behaving ideally? I tried repeating the same problem using the Nelson-Obert generalized compressibility chart and got Z1 = 0.975, which would yield v1 = 0.2313 when using v=Z1R'T/p

Answer (score 1):

I got the same answer that the book got.  Linear interpolation on v like you did is not accurate enough.  You expect the behavior to be close to that of an ideal gas.  So pv should be nearly constant.  Try interpolating on pv rather than on v and see what you get.

At p=0.06, pv=0.021029

At p=0.1, pv=0.020743

So, at p = 0.0904, pv=0.020812

v=0.020815/.0904 = 0.2302